# Creating entry in /proc from LKM

Tags: c, linux-kernel, kernel-module, kernel

I'm trying to create an entry in `/proc` so I can control my kernel module. I think I got the `write` part, but I can't figure out how the `read` part should work.

```
static char proc_data[1];

static ssize_t read_proc(struct file *file, char __user *buf, size_t count, loff_t *pos){
    int ret;
    if(pos > 0){
        ret = 0;
    }else{
        memcpy(buf, proc_data, 1);
        ret = 1;
    }
    return ret;
}

static ssize_t write_proc(struct file *file, const char __user *buf, size_t count, loff_t *pos){

    if(count > 2)
        return -EINVAL;

    if(copy_from_user(proc_data, buf, 1))
        return -EFAULT;

    if(strcmp("1", proc_data) == 0){
        //Do something
    }else if(strcmp("0", proc_data) == 0){
        //Undo something
    }

    return count;
}
```

If I return 1 from `read_proc`, if I cat my entry in `/proc`, it won't stop outputting the same value. If I return 0, it won't output anything. So I'm guessing I should return 1 the first time, then return 0, but I can't find out how.

Comment: Perhaps you should printk the parameters you receive from your first and subsequent calls... perhaps specifically the offset parameter. Are they not 0 / non-zero, as your code seems to already address?

Comment: @mah I thought about that, but I can't see any relation between them, as count is 65535 and pos it empty.

Comment: I would expect you'll receive the same size count in all cases (regardless of what the caller asks for) for block efficiency, and a pos that increases by that count size with each subsequent call from the same open. Keep in mind that kernel calls are expensive so the system wants to minimize them and will do this through large buffers that minimize the number of calls to be made.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In `.read` and `.write` callbacks, it is usually needed to update `loff_t *pos` before return.
If your module has read or written `count` bytes, increment `*pos` by that amount.

Besides that, note that when `.read` callback returns 0, it indicates an EOF. If it never returns 0, the system will loop indefinitely trying to "read the file to the end" when you `cat` the file. That is why returning 1 the first time and then 0 worked.

Comment: ```pos``` should be 0 the first time when my callback is called, right? I'm getting a really random and big negative number (around -131940446716000, give/take 100000). I'm using ```%lld and (long long int)pos``` in my ```printk```, is that correct?

Comment: @alexandernst, do you print `pos` or `*pos`? I did such mistake plenty of times. What you describe looks more like a pointer, the addresses of structures in the kernel are such negative numbers if represented as signed integers, at least on x86. I would expect `*pos` to be 0 on the first call of a callback.

Comment: Oops... I was printing ```pos``` instead of ```*pos``` indeed! What a silly mistake. Thank you :)